# using fixtures with a new created rails plugin, did not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures, testunit

When i create a plugin in rails like:

`rails plugin new test_plugin --full`


after this command, i create a model(like person) and try to use some fixtures or helper methods like:

`people(:one)`


to access the fixtures, but i do not have success with that.

i think rails should generate pre ready code to test, and I'm just asking it here cause i posted this on issues of rails and i don't have any help.
And if I'm the only one reproducing it, pls lets try to understand that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a bug on rails and i created a issue on github

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4971#issuecomment-6078279

now its working, tanks to the rails team.